# Is it possible a new user with low rep, using an SE app can not delete their own (held) question?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking on behalf of a new user who mentions that they don't see the delete option for [their question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22436/12102) which is now on hold. See [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22436/wobbling-trace-in-a-night-photograph-of-the-sky#comment63475_22436).

Is it possible that some combination of low rep, question-on-hold and use of an app could result in a situation where they might not be able to see a question delete option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android app does not support deletion of posts, even your own.  See the feature request [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216962)

The user would have to open the question in their browser in order to delete it. Mobile version of the site does have the "delete" link under posts.

Comment: Alex thank you for your speedy, accurate, and informative reply! I've up voted [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281120/303080) because of the specific problems not being able to delete even ones own question can cause.